# SQL statement issue using AND/OR

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I am trying to execute this SQL statement in phpMyAdmin however when I execute the statement below it returns all of the items regardless of whether the `type` is different to CREDIT rather than this one for an example.. -

`An item with CREDIT which level is REGULAR (therefore != PLATINUM or GOLD)`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `items` 
WHERE `purchased_by` = 0 
AND `type` = 'CREDIT' 
AND `level` != 'PLATINUM' 
OR `level` != 'GOLD' 
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Comment: Actually in reading the logic it seems like your `OR` just needs to be replaced with an `AND` because of the !=

Comment: I'd replace the last part with `AND level NOT IN ('PLATINUM', 'GOLD')`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are unfamiliar with basic logic, then use parentheses.  You don't seem to understand precedence for `AND` and `OR`.

In your case, though, you can fix the problem using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM items i
WHERE purchased_by = 0 AND
      type = 'CREDIT' AND
      level NOT IN ('PLATINUM', 'GOLD') 
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Note that you can also fix your logic by changing the `OR` to an `AND` -- that is actually the logic that you really want.  However, `NOT IN` is less ambiguous.  And, it's easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the order of operations so AND has a higher priority than OR so if you include parentheses it will fix the order for you. It would look like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `items` 
WHERE `purchased_by` = 0 
AND `type` = 'CREDIT' 
AND (`level` != 'PLATINUM' OR `level` != 'GOLD')
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Comment: This doesn't return all items now however it returns an item which `purchased_by = 0` and `type = 'CREDIT'` but `card_level = 'PLATINUM'`

Answer (score -1):

You should try both `AND/OR` like

```
SELECT * 
FROM `items` 
WHERE `purchased_by` = 0 
AND `type` = 'CREDIT' 
AND (`level` != 'PLATINUM' OR `level` != 'GOLD')
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Explanation:

Well as I added brackets for 2 clauses which are using OR so it means level is not platinum or not gold and rest all clauses are using AND.

That's bracket are setting prioritizing for these operator.

Comment: This doesn't return all items now however it returns an item which `purchased_by = 0` and `type = 'CREDIT'` but `card_level = 'PLATINUM'`

Comment: OK So you want all items having level Platinum and GOLD ? right ?

Comment: Why would you think the poster wants *all items having level *PLATINUM* and *GOLD*, when the question specifically uses `!=`?

Comment: Yes its using `!=` but there is `OR` in that so if it will pass first one, and in second clause of OR it will show all records again